# Assign key to array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Hi i am having a array like below

```
$scope.Selectedgroups =[183,184,24]
```

i need to convert to the below format

```
 [{groupId:183},{groupId:184},{groupId:24}];
```

trying to convert by using for loop

```
var groups=[]
        if($scope.Selectedgroups.length > 0){
            for(i=0; i< $scope.Selectedgroups.length; i++){
                groups.push({"groupId":$scope.Selectedgroups});
            }
        }
```

getting array format as below:

```
[{"groupId":[183,184,24]},{"groupId":[183,184,24]},{"groupId":[183,184,24]}]
```

any solution please

Comment: change as groups.push({"groupId":$scope.SelectedGroups[i]});

Comment: Thanq all i have changed the  groups.push({"groupId":$scope.Selectedgroups[i]}); and working great

Comment: @SudhirMN . but you don't need use any loop. You can use `map()`. Kindly check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should push the particular **`index`** value change it as

```
groups.push({"groupId":$scope.Selectedgroups[i]});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is problem in this line :

```
 groups.push({"groupId":$scope.Selectedgroups});
```

Please change this to :

```
 groups.push({"groupId":$scope.Selectedgroups[i]});
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the array position using index, like `$scope.Selectedgroups[i]`

```
for(i=0; i< $scope.Selectedgroups.length; i++){
      groups.push({"groupId":$scope.Selectedgroups[i]});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use --  $scope.Selectedgroups[i]     

         var groups=[]
            if($scope.Selectedgroups.length > 0){
                for(i=0; i< $scope.Selectedgroups.length; i++){
                    groups.push({"groupId":$scope.Selectedgroups[i]});
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.Selectedgroups =[183,184,24];
  $scope.temp=[];
 $scope.Selectedgroups.forEach(function(e){
    $scope.temp.push({groupId:e});
 })
 $scope.Selectedgroups=$scope.temp;
 console.log($scope.Selectedgroups);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **The problem is**, You should push the particular index of value to your groups array. to all other answers are explains very well.

---

**But I have an other answer 
,You can do this by using `map()` function to reducing  `loop` statement and few lines of code.**

```js
  var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
    app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
     $scope.Selectedgroups =[183,184,24];
     var groups=[]
      if($scope.Selectedgroups.length > 0){          
      groups = $scope.Selectedgroups.map(function(elem){    
         return {"groupId":elem};
      });
     }
     console.log(groups);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">

    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

 app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope,$filter) {
  $scope.Selectedgroups =[];
  var items = [183,184,24];
  for(i=0; i< items.length; i++){
   var obj = {};
   obj['groupId'] = items[i];
   $scope.Selectedgroups.push(obj);
  }
 });

</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
 {{Selectedgroups}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```